# Auto zoom HTML content in wkwebview

Tags: swift, wkwebview

In my app I have an option for the user to top up their wallet and this uses a payment gateway which is controlled within a wkwebview. In my Xcode simulator the OTP screen zooms automatically but on a hard iPhone device it does not.

How can I force the wkwebview to fit the screen with the content?

On my Xcode simulator the content zooms automatically.
[image]

On my iPhone it doe not.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In place after your webView initiated add this code:

```
let js = "var style = document.createElement('meta'); style.name = 'viewport'; style.content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'; document.head.appendChild(style);"
webView.evaluateJavaScript(js)
```

This code add small piece of js to the page and "execute" it. This js code turn off autoscaling effect. For me it work well.

Comment: It did not work for me unfortunately. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: can you provide code you use for wkwebview init and display and links you use, if possible. I wan't to try it out and see what happens and maybe help you with it I can find a solution for it.